# Timer in C# starts when the application starts rather than when I press the button

Tags: c#

I would appreciate your help. I am a total beginner and just about started to learn programming in C#.

I have a form ("ThisProgram") with 2 buttons.
1st button ("OK") is supposed to close the form and start an external program.
2nd button ("Later") is supposed to hide the form and show it again in 2 minutes.
textBox1 is there just for me to see the timer works.

I have 2 problems:

1) The timer that's supposed to open the window (ThisProgram.exe) again if you click "Later" starts when the program starts even if you don't click "Later"

2) Hide(); ... After putting this line in there, it will open the window in 2 minutes and then after another 2 minutes again and so on forever for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description of MainForm.
/// </summary>
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }

    int duration = 0;

    void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        duration++;
        textBox1.Text = duration.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\ThisProgram.exe";
        Process.Start(start);
        if (duration == 1)
        {
            Timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    void LaterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
        Hide();
    }

    void OKClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\OtherExternalProgram.exe";
        Process.Start(start);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help. If there's anything else wrong or strange in the code, I'd appreciate it too if you let me know.

Comment: We need to see the code for the timer from your designer file. Do you have `Enabled` set to `true` there?

Comment: You can check that by opening the form designer and looking at the timer properties

Comment: Set Timer.Enabled = false; in form constructor so it doesn't run until you press the click.

Comment: Oh, so this was it! Now everything works fine. Thank you for your help.